# Removing substrings from a shell variable

Tags: shell-script, string

I have some string that read like this one here

```
Dio - We Rock-Greatest Hits (2CD) (2004)
```

I use this

```
NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%'(" ")'* }
NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName//[^A-Za-z ]/ }
```

and it gives me this left over :

```
NewDirectoryName is -> Dio We Rock Greatest Hits Cd
```

it removes the `(2CD)` and `(2004)` alltogether leaving me with `Cd`.

What puzzles me is if it removes the `(2004)`, then why does it turn `(2CD)` into `Cd`. Why only remove `(2` and the `)` and why is it changing `D` to `d`?

How do I get rid of the entire thing to get this:

```
Dio We Rock Greatest Hits
```

Comment: Your first line does nothing. Is there a typo in it? Is the first lower-case `z` in `[^A-za-z ]` a typo? It should be an upper-case `Z`

Comment: yep type O should read [^A-Za-z ] I'll fix that thanks

Comment: youv'e got inner quotes in your `'(" ")'` pattern, but you don't have such in your match. and so you don't match. do `${var%%\(*}` to strip everything up to the first `(` character.

Answer (score 4):

As I commented, your first expansion does nothing. The literal string `(" ")` is not in the string so nothing is removed. Then then 2nd expansion removes all characters that are not a letter or a space. That's why "CD" stays. There's nothing in your code that would lower-case the "d" in "CD".

If you want to remove all bits in parentheses:

```
shopt -s extglob
NewDirectoryName='Dio - We Rock-Greatest Hits (2CD) (2004)'

NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName//\(*([^\)])\)}
# ...................................aa........cc
# .....................................bbbbbbbb
# (a) a literal open parenthesis
# (b) zero or more non-close-parenthesis characters
# (c) a literal close parenthesis

echo ">$NewDirectoryName<"
```

```
>Dio - We Rock-Greatest Hits  <
```

To remove trailing whitespace:

```
NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName%%+([[:blank:]])}
```

This uses "extended pattern matching" patterns, documented at the end of this section of the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: is there any advantage to using extended globs here?

Comment: You can't do "one or more non-whatever" without them -- glob patterns aren't that sophisticated

Comment: i dont follow. what one or more non whatevers are you looking for?

Comment: "zero or more non-close-parenthesis characters"

Comment: but the asker says *how can I get rid of everything in ()*? how does a name without them factor? im definitely missing something. sorry about that.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion: *how can I get rid of everything in ()* => `NewDirectoryName=${NewDirectoryName//\(*([^\)])\)}`

Comment: If we have `x="foo (bar) baz (qux) blah"`, then `${x//\(*\)}` is too greedy and removes "baz".

Comment: ahh. i see your point, and it is fair. i think it would be better highlighted in your answer though. though it is also hard for me to follow, i dont  see any indication in the question that a string like that might occur - they just ask about DIO - which rocks.